# cannot run condition if-else in django

Tags: django

I want to check if the user is logged in:

```
{% if userprofile.is_autenticated %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'kerajinan.views.profile' %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>{{ user.get_username }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}">Sign Out</a></li>
{% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

But when I'm already logged in, it uses this code:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
```

I made a custom user model to manage the users.

Comment: you have a typo `is_autenticated` should be `is_authenticated`

Comment: And are you sure you didn't mean `user` rather than `userprofile`?

Comment: @digitaldouble it sama not work

Comment: @Daniel i already use user but its same not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings` and you can read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/) for more info.